# How to make custom posts types display when published for the future

Tags: custom-post-types, functions

I'm having a hard time accomplishing two things. I've created a custom post type for Events. I would like for the client to be able to post the event by the date. This means publishing posts that are scheduled for the future to appear published. I would also like the posts to revert back to drafts once the date has passed. Anyone know how to accomplish this? Here's the code I've been toying with:

```
<?php 
// Register Custom Post Type: Events Posts

add_action('init', 'events_register');

function events_register() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Events', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Event', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Event item'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Event'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Event'),
        'new_item' => __('New Event'),
        'view_item' => __('View Event Item'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Events'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-calendar-alt',
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => 4,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
      ); 

    register_post_type( 'events' , $args );

    function setup_future_hook() {
        // Replace native future_post function with replacement
            remove_action('future_events','_future_post_hook');
            add_action('future_events','publish_future_post_now');
        }

        function publish_future_post_now($id) {
        // Set new post's post_status to "publish" rather than "future."
            wp_publish_post($id);
        }

        add_action('init', 'setup_future_hook');

}
```

?>

This is my loop:

```
<?php // WP_Query arguments
                $args = array (
                'post_type'              => array( 'events' ),
                'order'                  => 'ASC',
                'posts_per_page'         => '4',
                );

                // The Query
                $query = new WP_Query( $args );

                // The Loop
                if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                $query->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="event-box">
                        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                        <h5><?php the_field('venue_name'); ?></h5>
                        <div class="date"><?php the_date( 'F j, Y' ); ?></div> 
                        <div class="time"><?php the_field('event_time'); ?></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <a target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php the_field('buy_tickets_link'); ?>">Buy Tickets</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <a target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php the_field('venue_link'); ?>">Venue Info</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php }
                } else {
                // no posts found
                }

                // Restore original Post Data
                wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The most common solution for this is to save the event date in post meta and use that to query/order.

Comment: Thanks, Milo. How would I do that?